# ld: library not found for -lz

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4.2

This is driving me crazy, when i try to compile on the simulator, everything is ok, but on the device i got this error:

```
ld: library not found for -lz
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

Please help me understand the source of the problem:

```
    Ld /Users/ZConsulting/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Fontenay-sous-Bois-dhlecgdgtoldsadoctkyueriyius/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Fontenay-sous-Bois.app/Fontenay-sous-Bois normal armv7
        cd /Users/ZConsulting/Desktop/Fontenay-sous-Bois
        setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 5.0
        setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
        /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk -L/Users/ZConsulting/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Fontenay-sous-Bois-dhlecgdgtoldsadoctkyueriyius/Build/Products
/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/ZConsulting/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Fontenay-sous-Bois-dhlecgdgtoldsadoctkyueriyius/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs
/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/ZConsulting/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Fontenay-sous-Bois-dhlecgdgtoldsadoctkyueriyius/Build/Intermediates/Fontenay-sous-Bois.build/Debug-iphoneos/Fontenay-sous-Bois.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Fontenay-sous-Bois.LinkFileList -dead_strip -fobjc-arc -miphoneos-version-min=5.0 -framework SenTestingKit -lz -lz.1.1.3 -framework MobileCoreServices
 -framework SystemConfiguration -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreLocation -framework MapKit -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -o /Users/ZConsulting/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Fontenay-sous-Bois-dhlecgdgtoldsadoctkyueriyius/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Fontenay-sous-Bois.app/Fontenay-sous-Bois
```

**EDIT:**

I did import the libz.1.1.3.dylib framework:
[image]

The only libz that i got in the Linked frameworks is the `libz.1.1.3.dylib`
[image]

Answer (score 6):

You did specify the library `libz.dylib` in the `Linked frameworks and Libraries` item rather than the direct reference to `libz.1.1.3` - in general you should use the most generic version of a library for compilation rather than a more specific one

Secondly, make sure that the `libz.dylib` is present under the iOS SDK - if it's missing, then it may be a mis-installed SDK (reinstall should fix that).

i.e.

```
find /Developer/Platforms -name libz.dylib
```

should result in a non-empty output for a `libz.dylib` under `iPhoneOS5.0.sdk`

Also see the answer to [iPhone - Linker Error in Xcode 4.2 Preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932991/libz-dylib-versus-libz-1-2-3-dylib-versus-libz-1-2-5-dylib), which is a similar issue to this.

Comment: I have imported the libz.1.1.3.dylib library, please take a look on my edit, this is working with i compile with the simulator, but since i try to build an archive, i got that.

Comment: Yes, and the simulator uses a different location to the device. You're better off importing the generic `libz.dylib` rather than the specific `libz.1.1.3`. Try the `find /Developer/Platforms -name libz.1.1.3.dylib` and check that it is found in both `iPhoneOS5.0.sdk` *and* `iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk`. If it's not found, then I suggest replacing it with just `libz.dylib`. You should have a compelling reason for using the `1.1.3` version of libz to make reference to that specific version (in general these libraries are upwards compatible)

Comment: The only libz framework i got in the list is the `libz.1.1.3.dylib`, please have a look o my Update.

Comment: It looks like you have an invalid SDK install in that case - From my 5.0 SDK I see a bunch of `libz.*.dylibs` - `libz.1.1.3.dylib`, `libz.1.2.5.dylib`, `libz.1.dylib` `libz.dylib` and they're the only real file is libz.1.2.5.dylib; the rest are references to that file. I would suggest reinstalling Xcode 4.2 after performing a clean uninstall - follow the instructions in the About Xcode readme for uninstallation, and then reinstall it. Alternatively, use a .pkg extraction tool like pacifist and re-extract the iPhoneOS5.0.sdk over the current one.

Answer (score 2):

i got the same error with a different library:

```
ld: library not found for -lssl
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

to resolve this, under `search paths` -> `user header search paths` -> `release` i put:

```
"$(BUILD_ROOT)/../IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/include"
```

keep in mind that I get this bug only when I archive, and my archive is a based off my release scheme..

---

**update:**
I got the same problem (on a different occasion/project) for the `lpods` Library (ie cocoapods).. the way i figured out to solve this is by realizing that the build worked fine on my `development` scheme but not my `debug` scheme. basically the `development` scheme had **no** for `build active architectures only` whereas `debug` had yes. I simply changed `debug` to no in *all* the targets under cocoapods