# Problems trying to add the libz.1.2.3.dylib to my project

Tags: ios

i followed this steps

[image]

Delete libz.1.2.3 from your local Frameworks folder.

Select your project at the top of the Project Navigator.

Select your application target.

Open "Link Binary With Libraries".

Click the "+" only available libz.1.1.3.dylib file not available libz.1.2.3.dylib

[image]

i can't able to add libz.1.2.3.dylib.anyone help me how can i add this library file

Comment: "Delete libz.1.2.3 from your local Frameworks folder." - precisely why? And then why do you expect it to be there?

Comment: Why did you do `Delete libz.1.2.3 from your local Frameworks folder` if you want to add it?

Comment: unfortunately i deleted, Now i want add libz.1.2.3.dylib library to my project but not available in link binary with library. how can i add?

Comment: Ohh man.. Try to copy deleted framework from your colleague & paste it into the same folder. & then try adding it to you project.

Comment: Always make habit to remove reference instead of delete in the case of framework or apple provided files in Xcode.As you have deleted the file the file is parmantelly removed from your mac.

Comment: possible duplicate of [libz.dylib versus libz.1.2.3.dylib versus libz.1.2.5.dylib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932991/libz-dylib-versus-libz-1-2-3-dylib-versus-libz-1-2-5-dylib)

Answer (score 2):

Add libz.1.2.5.dylib it works fine in IOS 5 in Xcode 4.2