# Unzip files using libz.dylib

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, unzip, dylib

I am creating an application which unizp the files, after googling I found that we can use libz.dylib which is already available in Cocoa touch. What is strange to me that , I am not able to find any documents for libs.dylib. Can anyone provide me some official documentation ? And also if we want to unzip the files, everyone is suggesting to use some 3rd party libraries to unzip the files. Can't we do with the default libz.dylib ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can do like this way:-

i found one greate answer in stack overflow below from this link [download and unzip file in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11333399/download-and-unzip-file-in-ios) please check below

I've used [ZipArchive](http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/) with success in the past. It's pretty ligthweight and simple to use, supports password protection, multiple files inside a ZIP, as well as compress & decompress.

The basic usage is:

```
NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ZipFileName" ofType:@"zip"];
ZipArchive *zipArchive = [[ZipArchive alloc] init];
[zipArchive UnzipOpenFile:filepath Password:@"xxxxxx"];
[zipArchive UnzipFileTo:{pathToDirectory} overWrite:YES];
[zipArchive UnzipCloseFile];
[zipArchive release];
```

more examples about this package [here](http://transoceanic.blogspot.in/2011/07/compressuncompress-files-on.html)

I have also tried **[SSZipArchive](https://github.com/samsoffes/ssziparchive/blob/master/SSZipArchive.h)** in some projects.
Below line would unzip your zip file.

```
[SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:path toDestination:destination];
```

please also check the example hope its helps you :)

**Edit**

please visit this :-

[libz.dylib versus libz.1.2.3.dylib versus libz.1.2.5.dylib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932991/libz-dylib-versus-libz-1-2-3-dylib-versus-libz-1-2-5-dylib)

Comment: Thank you. Am using ZipArchive already. But all I want to know is, a apple documentation for libz.dylib and can we using any default API from that to extract the files ?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a try of [ZipArchive](https://github.com/mattconnolly/ZipArchive), which is the easiest lib I have used for zip/unzip affairs in both iOS and MacOS.

Comment: Thank you. Am using ZipArchive already. But all I want to know is, a apple documentation for libz.dylib and can we using any default API from that to extract the files ?

Comment: ZipArchive is short and to the point, very clean and I'd recommend it.