# adding libz.1.2.3.dylib vs libz.1.1.3.dylib or libz.1.2.5.dylib

Tags: ios, xcode

I am following [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2965/how-to-write-an-ios-app-that-uses-a-web-servicehttp://www.raywenderlich.com/2965/how-to-write-an-ios-app-that-uses-a-web-service)

The tutorial states to add `libz.1.2.3.dylib.` library, but because I have downloaded newer or older library (I don't know exactly if my library is newer or older that the library in the tutorial, but 99% it is newer). So, when I tried to add the `libz.1.2.3.dylib.` library, I didn't find it. However, when I typed `libz` I found these choices:

[image]

which one should I choose please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [libz.dylib versus libz.1.2.3.dylib versus libz.1.2.5.dylib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932991/libz-dylib-versus-libz-1-2-3-dylib-versus-libz-1-2-5-dylib)

Comment: Note to me and others read the related questions on the right before committing a question or answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In using dynamic libraries the one you normally use is libX.major_version.dylib in this case libz.1.2.dylib. This is a link to a library libX.major_version.minor_version.dylib which here is libz.1.2.5.dylib

The rationale for this is that the major version is changed only when the API is changed, the minor version is updated when any change is made. Thus your program should work when it uses any of the same major version and so you want the latest version.

In this case the tutorial had an older install and so its  libz.1.2.dylib. should have pointed to libz.1.2.3.dylib.

For you you should use libz.1.2.5.dylib which should be like the tutorials version but with bug fixes and possibly extra functions that don't matter here as the tutorial won't call the new functions.

Normally libX.1.x.dylib would be older than libX.2.y.dylib but the writers might produce bug fixes to the old API whilst also working on the new API

Following on from the rational I gave libz.dylib should be a link to the highest number library but I would not use it as you are writing to a particular API so I would use a version specific (In this case if missing a link the I would not trust what  libz.dylib points to)

Comment: ... so just add `libz.dylib`?

Comment: @trojanfoe no I guess 1.2.5,

Comment: Well there is something to be said for not tying your app to a specific version of the library as that will allow flexibility when it's deployed on different versions of OSX.