# Xcode 5.1: library not found for -lz.1.2.3

Tags: xcode, clang

This is a bugger and it's been frustrating me for some time.

I get this output when building my Xcode project:

> ld: library not found for -lz.1.2.3 clang: error: linker command
>   failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

The entire output:

```
Ld /Users/Yashwant/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LROAuth2Demo-eviojihhpjtuqxfkfctmczczudhr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/LROAuth2Demo.app/LROAuth2Demo normal i386
    cd /Users/Yashwant/Downloads/OAuth/LROAuth2Demo
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.1
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk -L/Users/Yashwant/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LROAuth2Demo-eviojihhpjtuqxfkfctmczczudhr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/Yashwant/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LROAuth2Demo-eviojihhpjtuqxfkfctmczczudhr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/Yashwant/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LROAuth2Demo-eviojihhpjtuqxfkfctmczczudhr/Build/Intermediates/LROAuth2Demo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/LROAuth2Demo.build/Objects-normal/i386/LROAuth2Demo.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=7.1 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework SystemConfiguration -framework CFNetwork -lz.1.2.3 -framework MobileCoreServices -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/Yashwant/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LROAuth2Demo-eviojihhpjtuqxfkfctmczczudhr/Build/Intermediates/LROAuth2Demo.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/LROAuth2Demo.build/Objects-normal/i386/LROAuth2Demo_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/Yashwant/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/LROAuth2Demo-eviojihhpjtuqxfkfctmczczudhr/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/LROAuth2Demo.app/LROAuth2Demo
```

I have had few "linker command" failures before, but they seem to be fixed by simply cleaning the project and re-building. In this case, I was pointed out that I had to install the command line developer tools for Xcode 5, but unfortunately the error still doesn't go away.

For complete assurance I checked if I had actually installed them by using `pkgutil --pkg-info=com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables` and it returns:

> package-id: com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables version:
>   5.1.0.0.1.1393561416 volume: / location: / install-time: 1396984437 groups: com.apple.FindSystemFiles.pkg-group
>   com.apple.DevToolsBoth.pkg-group
>   com.apple.DevToolsNonRelocatableShared.pkg-group

So I restarted my computer, but still no results.

Comment: Make sure you actually have that version of zlib installed. Do you have a different version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem as @photoionized pointed out was partly due to the version of `zlib` or `libz`. Because the project was old it was using `libz.1.2.3` instead of the latest `libz.1.2.5`. So to update that, I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6779951/xcode-4-2-link-error-libz-issue).

Basically I had to delete the old one and replace it with the new one.

> Link against the libz.dylib, but add it through the Build Phases tab.
>
> Project >> Target >> Build Phases >> Link Binary With Libraries
>
> Press + under the list and select the libz.dylib then it will add the
>   lib so it will work inbetween SDK updates.